# Pi phase shift b/w adjacent pixels while using fft2

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, gaussian, phase

I have a 2D Gaussian beam at its waist (where the phase is zero throughout the transverse plane). When I use fft2 to find the 2D spatial Fourier transform and plot the phase, I observe that there is a pi phase shift between any 2 adjacent data points. However, I don't observe this when I use for loops to calculate the Fourier transform instead of using fft2.

Is this due to phase wrapping? How do I overcome this?

Thanks.

Edit: I'm posting the code for the fft of a circular aperture, since the same results are observed, and because it is much simpler.

```
Nx = 200; Ny = Nx;

%creating coordinate grids
x = -Nx/2:Nx/2 - 1; y = -Ny/2:Ny/2 - 1;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);

r = 15; %radius of aperture

Eip = ((X.^2 + Y.^2 ) <= r^2); %aperture

figure;pcolor(abs(Eip));axis square; shading flat; colorbar;
figure;pcolor(angle(Eip));axis square; shading flat; colorbar;

Cip = fftshift(fft2(Eip)); %FFT

figure;pcolor(abs(Cip));axis square; shading flat; colorbar;
figure;pcolor(angle(Cip));axis square; shading flat; colorbar;
```

Comment: Some code and results you're getting could help people understand what you're dealing with and develop better hypothesis

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

`Cip` turns out to be real. You're just seeing sign changes between contiguous points.

### Long answer

`Eip` is obviously real. Besides, it exhibits the following symmetry along the x and y axes.  Let's take the x axis first. For any fixed `y`, consider `Eip` as a finite signal defined at `x` values `0`,`1`,...,`Nx-1`. If that finite signal is extended into a periodic sequence, then this periodic sequence turns out to be *even*. This is true for your specific definition of `Eip`. Together with the fact that the values are real, this implies<sup>1</sup> that the DFT along `x` is also real and has the same type of symmetry. Now, regarding the y axis, the same holds. The final result is that the 2D-DFT `Cip` is **real** and has the mentioned x and y **symmetries**.

(As a side note, `Cip` as obtained in your code is not real but complex. However, the imaginary part is of the order of `eps`, and thus negligible. You can check:

```
>> max(real(Cip(:)))
ans =
   709
>> max(imag(Cip(:)))
ans =
  4.6262e-014
```

So the imaginary part is only an artifact of finite numerical precision. We can do

```
Cip = real(Cip);
```

to remove that spurious imaginary part.)

Now that we know that `Cip` is real (up to numerical precision), it's natural that all its values have phase either `0` or `pi` (or equivalently `-pi`). That is, what you are seeing is just changes of sign between consecutive values in the DFT. To illustrate, see the following graph, which  shows the variation of `Cip` along a line parallel to the `y` axis (corresponding to `x` equal to 120; just as an example):

```
stem(1:Nx, Cip(120,:))
```

[image]

<sup><sup>1</sup>
See *Discrete-time signal processing*, Oppenheim *et al.*, 2nd ed., pp. 568--570.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, but I guess the underlying question is why there should be sign changes in the real part of the Fourier transform?

Comment: @maxwellsapprentice Well... why should _not_ there be sign changes? The Fourier transform of something as simple as a rectangular pulse is a sinc function, which has sign changes

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this, you need an additional `ifftshift`.
This is due to the algorithm Matlab uses and the results you expect.
To avoid the pi phase jumps use this instead:

```
fftshift(fft2(ifftshift(Eip)));
```